# compiler failure in c++ 20 using the new semaphore library

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c++20

c++20 introduced the  library, however i'm unable to use it.

this is my compile line: `g++-10 -std=c++20 sem.cpp -o sem`

the error that I get is:

```
sem.cpp:4:10: fatal error: semaphore: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <semaphore>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I tried using a different compiler `clang++` but it didn't make any difference.

Using Linux.

Comment: Which compiler versions you are using? Have you tried current development snapshots?

Comment: They may not be implemented by those standard libraries yet.

Comment: not implemented yet: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Answer (score 2):

GCC/libstdc++ 10 lacked support for this C++20 feature.

GCC 11 (released April 2021) provides the `semaphore` header file as do recent versions of Clang and MSVC.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support